# Calculating the value of an integrals derivative given then value of the integral

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I am given the following informations about a function:
$$f\in C^1(\mathbb{R}),\quad f(3)=7,f(7)=13,\quad \int_{3}^{13}f'(x)\,dx=12$$
and i need to find the value of
$$\int_{7}^{13}f'(x)\,dx.$$

A starting point would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Fundamental, dear OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral condition gives $f(13)-f(3)=12$, and since $f(3)=7$, this implies $f(13)=19$. Now:
$$\int_{7}^{13}f'(x)\,dx = f(13)-f(7) = 19-13 = 6.$$

Comment: Wow thanks so much, that has cleared it up alot more for me! Actually a pretty straight forward question , just my lack of knowledge of some basics makes it difficult